# Is there a design reason why Git commits only store pointers to their parents, not children?

Tags: design, git

Git commits contain pointers to their parent commit(s). Is there a reason why they don't also contain pointers to their child commits?

I get that there's a problem of data duplication, in that you'd have to update both parent and child commit objects. But apart from that it seems like there'd be an advantage in terms of reachability, being able to traverse the commit graph both backwards and forwards. E.g. if you're on a commit with multiple children all on different branches, you could reach all the children just based on that commit if you know the object IDs of the child commits.

Is there a design reason why Git opted not to do this? Do other VCSs do this successfully?

Comment: Can you explain how a commit would point to a child commit that will only be created next year by a person you don't know?

Comment: Once you read in the data, your in-memory representation of the graph can differ from the file structure, that's entirely up to you. If you want bidirectional links, you can have bidirectional links.

Answer (score 11):

Git is a *distributed* version control system. It's always possible to know that the parent commit of your commit was, since you need it to create the commit, but it's fundamentally impossible to enumerate all child commits. Anyone with access might have cloned the repo and created additional child commits, and you'd never know.

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't think about it from the dvcs point of view

Answer (score 10):

A Git commit is an *immutable* object that represents a state/snapshot of a project, and all of the history leading up to the state. Thus, each commit must contain the IDs (pointers) of its base commits.

Git objects are hashed to derive their ID. This leads to a content-addressable design that provides some benefits such as easy synchronization, cheap branching, and integrity checking. The integrity checks can detect accidental corruption in a Git database, a problem that plagued predecessors like SVN. But it also assists with security: it's impossible to later manipulate a commit to insert malicious content (leaving aside problems like SHA-1 collisions).

If we were to update a commit object each time that it's referenced by another commit, this would change its ID, which would require updating all other commits that reference it, which would require rewriting the entire Git database for even such innocuous changes like git-stashing some changes for later. The child references also only make sense within a repository, but not if commits are pushed/pulled to/from another repository.

Other designs for distributed version control systems are possible. For example, we could identify commits via an UUID, and verify integrity via external checksums. This would allow us to update commit contents later. But that would be more complicated, could raise security issues, and cannot be retro-fit into Git's design.

Of course, keeping track of child commits doesn't require changing the commits. These relationships could be tracked in separate indexes, and I think Git does maintain indexes for other purposes. I guess the problem of finding all child commit objects in a Git database is not needed that frequently, especially since Git's data model also supports commits that are not reachable from any branch or tag (e.g. see the git-reflog for recent commit objects, especially after a rebase).

Comment: Commits being immutable is essential for the distributed nature of Git. If they were just numbers, for example, my commit 3453 might not be the same as your commit 3453. But my commit 998a13f6... is always the same as yours, if we both have it.

Answer (score 6):

It’s a requirement and a consistency reason:

- git doesn’t need the pointer to child to operate and provide its core functions. So why make it more complex ?
- at the time the commit is done, the parent is known, the child is yet not written. It’s therefore easy to add the new record with only the pointer to the parent:

  - If a parallel process is reading the git entries, it will always be consistent: either it starts at a the parent or it starts at the child. But the entries read are always correct and consistent.
  - Changing the parent to make it point to the child is more delicate, since during the update of the record, the file could be temporarily inconsistent. This means that if a parallel process would read the gitfile, it might read the record of the parent in an inconsistent state (e.g. child already exist but not yet - or partially updated)

Last but not least, a comit is always done on one parent. But a parent could have multiple childs accross the branches.